# how to get skype from android market place

Tags: android, emulation

i have an android emulator installed that has an android market app on its emulator..i have installed many apps from that,i want to download skype app from over there but  there is  no app by name skype at all...

plz anyone help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Skype is a free application, it appears to be restricted geographically the same way paid apps are (maybe even to the same countries). So you need to be connecting to the market from an IP address on a supported carrier's network, AND have a SIM card from one of the supported carriers inserted (this was my experience trying to install it on a trip to the UK recently).

Comment: hi thanks but i am not asking skype on real device..i want it on my emulator....

Answer (score 0):

Try getting Skype on your phone, use a backup-program to back it to your SD Card, then get it fom SDCard to emulator

Comment: hi thanks a lot can plz plz tel me

Comment: hi thanks but the real scenario is right now i don't have any mobile with me,i am just working on eclipse with related sdk and jdk..i have an android market app on my emulator, i want to install skype from that emulator not from the real device....plz help me out